# Update exsisting JSON file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to update exsisting JSON file when running my code by adding additional data (package_id). this is the exsisting json contents:

```
{
  "1": {
    "age": 10,
    "name": [
      "ramsi",
      "jack",
      "adem",
      "sara",
    ],
    "skills": []
  }
}
```

and I want to insert a new package and should looks like this:

```
{"1": {
    "age": 10,
    "name": [
      "ramsi",
      "jack",
      "adem",
      "sara",
    ],
    "skills": []
  } "2": {
    "age": 14,
    "name": [
      "maya",
      "raji",
    ],
    "skills": ["writing"]
  }
}
```

Issue is when I add the new data it adds --> ({) so (one top-level value) is added twice which is not allowed by JSON standards

```
    {"1": {
    "age": 10,
    "name": [
      "ramsi",
      "jack",
      "adem",
      "sara",
    ],
    "skills": []
  }} {"2": {
    "age": 14,
    "name": [
      "maya",
      "raji",
    ],
    "skills": ["writing"]
  }
}
```

and this is my code to add the new (package_id):

```
        list1[package_id] = {"age": x, "name": y, "skills": z}
        ss = json.dumps(list1, indent=2)
            data = []
            with open('file.json', 'r+') as f:
                data = json.loads(f.read())
                data1 = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
                f.seek(0) 
                f.write(data1)
                f.write(ss)
                f.truncate()
```

I write to the file twice because if I didn't store existing contents and write it again then it will remove old data and keeps only package_id number 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way.  You can't add to a JSON record by appending another JSON record.  A JSON file always has exactly one object.  You need to modify that object.

```
with open('file.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
data[package_id] = {'age':x, 'name':y, 'skills':z}
with open('file.json','w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data,indent=2))
```